# Axelar Transaction mined but execution failed on CallContractWithToken

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, axelar

I am trying to see if I can make Axelar send aUSDC from Optimism Goerli to Base Goerli.  Attached below, I've written two contracts, OPSender.sol and BaseReceiver.sol, and deployed it on Optimism Goerli and Base Goerli, respectively.  I tried calling the sendToMany function on OPSender to send the aUSDC from OP Goerli to Base Goerli, however I got the error
`Transaction mined but execution failed`

I am running everything on Remix IDE.

Here are the parameters I put into sendToMany

```
{
    "string _destChain": "Base",
    "string _destContractAddr": "0x291b1B6EB9DE79f0cb181bCF68Ae1ea70d9B8760",
    "address[] _destinationAddrs": [
        "0xD1872508B5A49eD6Ea5EefD93e643623c0F83a78"
    ],
    "string _symbol": "aUSDC",
    "uint256 _amount": "100"
}

val    10000000000000000 wei
```

Here is the tx

tx : https://goerli-optimism.etherscan.io/tx/0xa8cf2c170326dc27905f6a88c50db0e67630ce97345cb0a4d319e5fe4998b6ae

I put the tx into tenderly to try and debug and it gave me an arthimetic error (arthimetic overflow / underflow), however I'm not dealing with much math here.

Here are the contracts

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import { IERC20 } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol';
import { IAxelarGateway } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IAxelarExecutable.sol';
import { IAxelarGasService } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IAxelarGasService.sol';

contract OPSender {
    IAxelarGasService gasReceiver;
    IAxelarGateway gateway;

    constructor (
        address _gateway,
        address _gasReceiver
    ) {
        gateway = IAxelarGateway(_gateway);
        gasReceiver = IAxelarGasService(_gasReceiver);
    }

    function sendToMany(
        string memory _destChain,
        string memory _destContractAddr,
        address[] calldata _destinationAddrs,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _amount
    ) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Gas payment required");

        // get token address from symbol
        address tokenAddress = gateway.tokenAddresses(_symbol);

        // send funds to this contract
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        // approve gateway to spend funds
        IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(address(gateway), _amount);

        // encode recipient addresses tx on destination chain
        bytes memory _payload = abi.encode(_destinationAddrs);
        
        //pay gas from source chain
        gasReceiver.payNativeGasForContractCallWithToken{value: msg.value} (
            address(this),
            _destChain,
            _destContractAddr,
            _payload,
            _symbol,
            _amount,
            msg.sender
        );

        // send token and execute call
        gateway.callContractWithToken(
            _destChain,
            _destContractAddr,
            _payload,
            _symbol,
            _amount
        );
    }
}
```

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import { IERC20 } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol';
import { IAxelarExecutable } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IAxelarExecutable.sol';
import { IAxelarGasService } from '@axelar-network/axelar-cgp-solidity/contracts/interfaces/IAxelarGasService.sol';

contract BaseReceiver is IAxelarExecutable {
    IAxelarGasService public immutable gasService;

    constructor (address _gateway, address _gasService) 
        IAxelarExecutable(_gateway) 
    {
        gasService = IAxelarGasService(_gasService);
    }

    event Executed();

    function _executeWithToken(
        string memory,
        string memory,
        bytes calldata _payload,
        string memory _tokenSymbol,
        uint256 _amount
    ) internal override {
        // decode recipients
        address[] memory recipients = abi.decode(_payload, (address[]));

        // get token addr
        address tokenAddress = gateway.tokenAddresses(_tokenSymbol);

        // get first address
        address recipient = recipients[0];

        // transfer to recipient  
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(recipient, _amount);

        emit Executed();
    }
}
```

I am not sure why when I call the `sendToMany()` function I get the `Transaction mined but execution failed` error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing step here is approval, you need to approve the amount to be spent spent by the contract before calling the `sendToMany` function.

Check this guide: https://axelar.network/blog/cross-chain-airdrop-dapp-tutorial scroll to the `Implementing smart-contract write functionality` section to see how the approval is done on the frontend before calling the `sendToMany` function.

Or you can approve directly on the aUSDC contract in Optimism Goerli https://goerli-optimism.etherscan.io/address/0x254d06f33bDc5b8ee05b2ea472107E300226659A#writeContract

Note: The arithmetic error (arithmetic overflow/underflow) occurs because the amount is currently 0. The error arises from an attempt to divide by 0. However, once you approve the spender amount, a valid value will be present, and as a result, such an error will no longer occur.